# SWFObject / load smil file

Tags: javascript, swfobject

Why is this not working?

```
<div class="videocontainer" id='mediaspace-55'></div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js?ver=3.0.1'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'><!--
            var flashvars = {
              provider: "highwinds",
              file: "http://hwcdn.net/XXXXX/fms/pathtofile.smil",
              image: "test.jpg"
            };
            var params = {
              allowfullscreen: "true",
              allowscriptaccess: "always"
            };
            var attributes = {
              id: "mediaspace-55",
              name: "mediaspace-55"
            };
            swfobject.embedSWF("player.swf", "mpl55", "710", "420", "9.0.0","expressinstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

//            playerReady('mediaspace-55', 'additional_variable');
    //-->
</script>
```

I verified that all the linked files exists.

I spent days working on this simple javascript functionality (I am not a javascript programmer) and now that I want to finalize the project, it stopped working. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the API has changed, try this:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://mydomain.com/player/player.swf", "mpl55", "710", "420", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf");
```

Documentation here: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

Comment: That worked. I guess. Because now I no longer receive a javascript error. But the player is not loaded... the div container stays empty.

Comment: I was able to find the error. The second parameter of the embedSWF function is supposed to be the id of the div container.